# write a statistical model for this graph below

Tags: regression

[image]

2. Suppose that your employer has asked you to build a model.  When you plot the data in a scatter diagram, they behave in the following way:

Comment: A simple straight line looks insufficient, and a simple sine wave by itself also looks insufficient. Maybe a sine wave plus a straight line?